# How to avoid lambda functions with a known function parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, std-function

In the following code, I have a variable called `data`. It holds a functions inside itself to call them later. Let's assume `data` is defined in another library and I cannot change its type. I assign a template function to each member of it where a portion of this function is known (`s3`) and a portion must be given when it is called (`true`). I cannot pass something like this:

```
data[0]=test_func(?,s3);  // error
```

instead, I have to pass a lambda function to it :

```
data[0]=[](bool b){test_func(b,s3);}; // ok
```

But the lambda function does not look neat especially when we have an array of 100 of these assignments. It there any way to avoid lambda functions by just changing the `test_func` in any way? even using lambda inside `test_func` is ok to me because it is just written once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename F>
void test_func(bool b,F f)
{
    if(b)
        f();
}

void s1()
{
    std::cout<<"s1 \n";
}

void s2()
{
    std::cout<<"s2 \n";
}

void s3()
{
    std::cout<<"s3 \n";
}

int main()
{
    test_func(true,s1);
    test_func(true,s2);
    test_func(false,s1);
    test_func(true,s2);
    /////////////////
    std::function<void(bool)> data[100];
    // data=test_func(?,s3);  // error
    data[0]=[](bool b){test_func(b,s3);}; // ok
    data[0](true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that just `std::function<void (bool)> foo(F f) { return [](bool b) { test_func(b, f); }; }`?

Comment: As it is right now, the best solution is to simply use the lambda function. `std::bind` tried to do this, but using it requires learning its mini-language (for anyone who reads the code), and tends to make it harder for the compiler to optimize. Furthermore, it ends up barely shorter than the lambda function.

Comment: @melpomene, How do you fit it into this code?

Comment: @Justin, can a function returns lambda? like `combine(test_func,s3)`.

Comment: @ar2015 `data[0] = foo(s3);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid a `lambda` function completely as well as `templates` you can use a functional (class with `operator()`):

```
typedef void (&F)(void);
class TestFunc {
    F f;
    public:
    TestFunc(const F f) : f(f) {}
    void operator()(bool B) const { 
        if(B) f(); 
    }
};
```

Assign it with `TestFunc(s3)`. Just `typedef` `F` to the function type, no need for a template:

```
typedef void (&F)(void);
```

and remove the template completely - I usually prefer less templates if possible, but that's taste. A template would only really be called for if you need different function signature support.

To use a standard library functional just change the `typedef`:

```
typedef std::function<void(void)> F;
```

Comment: `template<typename F>`? `error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Functional’ with no type`

Comment: thanks a lot. can this solution be extended to `std::function` too?

Answer (score 2):

If each `s_n` is a regular function with an identical signature, you can just remove that `f` parameter from `test_func` and instead pass the function itself as template parameter.

```
template<void(&f)()>
void test_func(bool b)
{
    if(b)
        f();
}
```

And use like this:

```
data[0] = test_func<s1>;
```

Function pointers and references are explicitly allowed as template non-type parameters by [[temp.param/4]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#4):

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following
>   (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> [...]
>
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,
> - lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,

Comment: hi bro again. can it be done by std::function instead of pointers too?

Comment: @ar2015 - No. because for starters a `std::function` cannot be a constant expression. It has state to allow type erasure. A function pointer is only allowed because it's "fixed" in compile time too, in a sense.

Comment: Does it mean that pointers are superior to `std::function` in terms of optimization?

Comment: @ar2015 - One cannot make such a blanket statement. `std::function` exists to solve a specific problem. That's not without overhead, of course, but there is no way to do it with regular functions. The only stark improvement I can see, is that if a function is inline-able, a compiler will see it from the function reference of the template argument as if you wrote it directly in the templates body.

Comment: @ar2015 - But you should focus on correctness first. Premature optimization (and concern for it) are the root of many software problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your lambda in a helper function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

template<typename F>
void test_func(bool b,F f) {
    if(b) {
       f();
    }
}

std::function<void(bool)> wrap_function(const std::function<void(void)> &f) {
    return [f](bool b){test_func(b,f);};
}

void s1() {
    std::cout<<"s1 \n";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::function<void(bool)>> data;

    data.push_back(wrap_function(s1));

    data[0](true);
}
```

And you should use `std::vector`, `std::array` or another std container instead of `std::function<void(bool)> data[100]`